# Adafruit BNO08x Lib Not working with PicoRP2040 - PlatformIO

Tags: arduino, i2c, adafruit, platformio, rp2040

I was trying to connect the BNO08x IMU Breakout board with Pico RP2040, I tried connecting it to both the I2C ports, but it didnt worked.
I am using the official Adafruit BNO08x lib.
Below is the part of Example code included in the lib which I was trying to run:

```c
#include <Adafruit_BNO08x.h>

// For SPI mode, we need a CS pin
#define BNO08X_CS 10
#define BNO08X_INT 9

// For SPI mode, we also need a RESET 
// #define BNO08X_RESET 5
// but not for I2C or UART
#define BNO08X_RESET -1

Adafruit_BNO08x  bno08x(BNO08X_RESET);
sh2_SensorValue_t sensorValue;

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) delay(10); // will pause Zero, Leonardo, etc until serial console opens

  Serial.println("Adafruit BNO08x test!");

  // Try to initialize!
  if (!bno08x.begin_I2C()) {
  // if (!bno08x.begin_UART(&Serial1)) { // Requires a device with > 300 byte UART buffer!
  // if (!bno08x.begin_SPI(BNO08X_CS, BNO08X_INT)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to find BNO08x chip");
    while (1) { delay(10); }
  }
  Serial.println("BNO08x Found!");
```

I change the framework from Arduino to Earphilhower too, it didnt work.
Soon realised that I need to change the I2C pin defination, not sure how to do that, also this was the message I got in the serial monitor:

```
1Adafruit BNO08x test!
I2C address not found
Failed to find BNO08x chip
```

Comment: Where exactly you connect the SDA and SCL to on the Pico? If you are using Earphihower Arduino Pico framework, the default pins for I2C0 is 26 for SDA and 27 for SCL, and I2C1 is 4 for SDA and 5 for SCL.

Answer (score 0):

This library depends on Adafruit BusIO and unified sensor libraries, you need to download and include them in the code

Comment: Its already there in the Project libdep folder